# Gstreamer Timeoverlay componet Not starting from 0:0:0

Tags: video, overlay, gstreamer

I have gstreamer pipeline which overlays the time on video and display it.

This is the below pipeline.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/uurmi/Desktop/VIDEO_101027_0.asf ! decodebin ! timeoverlay shaded-background=true font-desc="Sans, 25" halignment=1 valignment=4 ! xvimagesink
```

For the above file time is starting from 0:0:0.0 only.

**But when i used .VOB extension file then time is starting from 0:14:24.0.**

This is the pipeline i have used,

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/uurmi/Desktop/VTS_01_2.VOB ! decodebin ! timeoverlay shaded-background=true font-desc="Sans, 25" halignment=1 valignment=4 ! xvimagesink
```

Here is the log when debug level is 3.

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.027069131 18247       0xf31840 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3483:gst_base_src_start_complete:<filesrc0> pad not activated yet
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Redistribute latency...
0:00:00.040136086 18247 0x7fe7f00024f0 WARN                   libav gstavviddec.c:1289:gst_ffmpegviddec_video_frame: Change in interlacing ! picture:1, recorded:0
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Execution ended after 0:00:03.079913046
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...


New clock: GstSystemClock
^[[B0:01:19.945336482 18288 0x7fb33024ed00 ERROR                  libav :0:: ac-tex damaged at 42 19
0:01:19.945470619 18288 0x7fb3300024f0 ERROR                  libav :0:: Warning MVs not available
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:01:19.903521354
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

What is the reason for that? and How to resolve it?

Comment: well at least give us some logs..

Comment: added log details here

Comment: no idea so far, try without GST_DEBUG and add identity after decodebin: `filesrc .. ! decodebin ! identity silent=false ! timeoverlay ! xvimagesink -v` you should see the timestamps which are used for time display.. do this for vob/asf and compare timestamps if they begin from 0..

Comment: i added the identity, then also i haven't observed any difference. The problem still there...

Comment: the identity is not for fixing the problem but for analysing :) you should get used to it, its very good for analysing events/messages and timing issues (or when some element blocks..) ... or do you mean the timestamps were both from vob/asf starting at 0:00:00 right?

Comment: yeah. for both video formats it should start from 0:00:00. K, i will try to analyze it, if you had any solution, make a note on me.